# Unable to run OpenTok's WebRTC demo

Tags: php, webrtc, livechat, opentok

Recently I tried to use OpenTok's WebRTC demo for a web application requiring peer-to-peer video/audio communication.

I went through the tutorials on http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/webrtc/docs/js/tutorials/ and http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/docs/server/server_side_libraries.html and I got something working using JavaScript (client-side) and PHP's library (server-side) for token/session generation.

I managed to code a basic peer-to-peer chat room *locally*. However, as soon as I upload it to a web server it blows up returning the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RequestException' with message 'Request error: Failed
to connect to 70.42.47.98: Permission denied' in /home/www/dummy_url.com/php-
sdk/SDK/Opentok-PHP-SDK/OpenTokSDK.php:192 Stack trace: #0 /home/www/dummy_url.com/php-
sdk/SDK/Opentok-PHP-SDK/OpenTokSDK.php(107): OpenTokSDK->_do_request('/session/create',
Array) #1 /home/www/dummy_url.com/php-sdk/SDK/Opentok-PHP-SDK/OpenTokSDK.php(221): 
OpenTokSDK->createSession('74.96.245.119', Array) #2 /home/www/dummy_url.com/php-
sdk/index.php(16): OpenTokSDK->create_session('74.96.245.119', Array) #3 {main} thrown
in /home/www/dummy_url.com/php-sdk/SDK/Opentok-PHP-SDK/OpenTokSDK.php on line 192
```

I took a look at line 192:

```
//die(function_exists('curl_version')); // debugging
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    throw new RequestException('Request error: ' . curl_error($ch)); // <=== LINE 192
}
curl_close($ch);
```

and verified the server had curl enabled. It does.

Then I tried to run the demo test and it fails at:

```
Assertion Failed: File '/home/www/skillfullearning.net/test/test/TestOpenTokSDK.php'
Line '102'
Code ''
```

What's in Line '102'? This:

```
...
$token = $a->generateToken("mysession", RoleConstants::MODERATOR, gmmktime() + 100000);
assert('$token');

$token = $a->generateToken("mysession", RoleConstants::MODERATOR, gmmktime());
assert('$token');

try {
$token = $a->generateToken("mysession", RoleConstants::MODERATOR, gmmktime() + 
1000000);
assert(false);
} catch (Exception $e) {
assert('$e'); // <================ LINE 102
}
...
```

I really don't know where to go from here. I would really appreciate some help with this matter.

/E

Comment: your remote host might be blocking socket connections

Comment: Thanks for the response, @DevZer0. How could I verify this is in fact happening? I have the feeling that could be it since it's not allowing me to generate session id and token from server side library. However, it runs perfectly when I generate session it and token from opentok.com and just hard code it into my file. Thanks again, sir.

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused by outdated tests. [Here is an outstanding issue](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-PHP-SDK/issues/10), hopefully it will be resolved soon. if you simply remove the test files, you would not have that problem anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't solve my problem. Please, refer to this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690086/unable-to-run-opentoks-webrtc-demo#comment26096660_17690086). The problem is I cannot generate session ids nor tokens from php's server side library. Any other ideas? Thanks!